# MCSessionDelegate Requires Class to Conform to NSObjectProtocol

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

I was trying to use the MultipeerConnectivity library from Apple but my class would not stop throwing the error "Type LocalClient does not conform to NSObjectProtocol". Am I missing anything that would cause this error?

```
import Foundation
import MultipeerConnectivity

class LocalClient : MCSessionDelegate {
    var availableServers : [Int]
    var session : MCSession
    var peerID : MCPeerID
    var browser : MCBrowserViewController

    init(name : String) {
        peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: name)

        session = MCSession(peer: peerID)
        session.delegate = self

        browser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "JoinGame", session: session)
    }

    func session(session: MCSession!, peer peerID: MCPeerID!, didChangeState state: MCSessionState) {

    }

    func session(session: MCSession!, didReceiveData data: NSData!, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!) {

    }

    func session(session: MCSession!, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String!, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!, withProgress progress: NSProgress!) {

    }

    func session(session: MCSession!, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String!, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!, atURL localURL: NSURL!, withError error: NSError!) {

    }

    func session(session: MCSession!, didReceiveStream stream: NSInputStream!, withName streamName: String!, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!) {

    }

}
```

Edit: Formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MCSessionDelegate` protocol is derived from `NSObjectProtocol`.
Therefore your class should be a subclass of `NSObject` so that it inherits all the `NSObjectProtocol` methods:

```
class LocalClient : NSObject, MCSessionDelegate {  }
```

This also requires you to call `super.init()` (after values have been
assigned to all properties):

```
init(name : String) {
    peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: name)
    session = MCSession(peer: peerID)
    availableServers = []
    browser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "JoinGame", session: session)

    super.init()

    session.delegate = self
}
```